# Generating complex antisymmetric matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, gaussian, sampling

Is there any possibility to generate Gaussian random complex antisymmetric matrices in Matlab?
I have tried using randn(M). But that simply gives random matrices of Gaussian distribution.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by a random Gaussian matrix. Should the entries be i.i.d? Circularly symmetric? See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

This will deliver you a Gaussian random complex antisymmetric matrix M with numbers from 0 to x. If you change x, you change the upper limit of the RNG.

```
n = 5; %rows and columns
M = ones(n,n); %matrix initiation
x = 50; %limit of random number generator; 

for i = 1 : n

   M(i,:) = complex(round(50.*randn(1,n)),round(50.*randn(1,n))); %generate random number for the row;
   M(:,i) = M(i,:).'; % take the same number and put it in the antisymmetric slot

end %for
```